# How to display background images from CSS included by modules

Tags: theming, 6

I'm working to take a single page "site" built in jquery/css and convert it to a D6 module.

the code contains more than one css file which has classes like this:

```
background: url('images/stadium.jpg') no-repeat left top;
```

The question I have is:
How do I get those images recognized?

Normally, in the tpl.php files I include with my module I set up my image like this and everything is fine:

```
<img src="print base_path().drupal_get_path('module','my_module'); /images/my_image.png" />
```

I don't know how to get images call from css classes to appear, and I can't build the path out all the way manually since I don't know where, or in what theme my module may end up.

If anyone has any ideas, or docs they can point me to I'd appreciate it.
if you need any clarification please let me know.

Thanks!
Steph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically given:

```
background: url('images/stadium.jpg') no-repeat left top;
```

The image will be loaded from the path relative to the CSS file.

e.g:

```
/styles.css
/images/stadium.jpg
```

The image is loaded from the relative 'images' subfolder.

Presumably, if the design is all controlled by a module, you could [drupal_add_css](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/6) the css file and have the image files relative to that in the module folder.

Comment: In my module I am using drupal_add_css to include my css files, and thats working fine, but the relative images in those css files are not showing. I'm not sure how I'd use drupal_add_css to include those images as well, can you elaborate? thanks for answering!

Comment: you'll need a folder 'images' in your module dir for those css images, it needs to be relative to the stylesheet path in the html source

Comment: thats got it, I had the images dir but my path wasn't right. thank you so much for the help!